# Uncaught TypeError cannot set property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, html

So on my [new website](http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/new) in google chrome, I am trying to make the images switch every 5 seconds using a setInterval function. This seems to work, however I have the problem cannot set property src of null.

```
var images = new Array();
images[0] = "/images/grilled-chicken-large.png";
images[1] = "/images/sizzly-steak.png";
var img = document.getElementById("img");

function changeImage() {
     for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        img.src = images[i];
        if (i == 2){i = i - 2;};
     }
}

window.onload=setInterval("changeImage()", 5000);
```

I know the problem is that I am trying to get the element with an id of img before the page is done loading, but I've already got a window.onload, so i don't know what to do. Also, if i make an init() function containing the setInterval and the img variable, the page freezes.

Any ideas?

Comment: You only have `images[0]` and `images[1]`, but you're trying to access `images[2]`.

Comment: Side note: don't pass strings to `setInterval`, it uses `eval`.  Pass functions: `setInterval(changeImage, 5000);`.  Also, `window.onload = setInterval(changeImage, 5000);` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: yea just realized that bfavaretto, thanks. Rocket, do you mean just pass it as changeImage() instead of "changeImage()"? And what do you mean by the last line not doing what I think it does?

Comment: @Ilan: Bit too much for comments, please create separate questions for them. The last line executes `setInterval`, immediately then assigns the result of that method (it's an integer used as ID) to `window.onload`, which does not make sense. See my anwer, I've added the `onload` stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you access element `2` of an array with only two elements (0 and 1).

But there is also a logical error in your script: Where do you store the index of the currently visible image? You need a global variable which holds that index.

```
var currentIndex = 0;
function changeImage() {
    // Switch currentIndex in a loop
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex >= images.length)
        currentIndex = 0;

    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    img.src = images[currentIndex];
}

document.onload = function() {
    setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
}
```

I've moved the `img` variable into the function so that it is assigned after five seconds when the document has loaded.

Just to clear things up: JavaScript is an event-based programming language. That means that the slideshow-change code is executed every time the interval fires, does some work (switch to the next slide) and then is done, so that the browser can render the page. If you iterate through the slides in a loop, there is no way for the browser to show the new slide because the script is still executing between the slides. The solution is what I've posted: Define a global variable that replaces the loop variable, and increment it every time the next slide is to be shown.

Comment: Yogu, what if i make it for (var i = 0, i<images.length, i++) { }? That should fix things, right?

Comment: Yogu, thanks for your help, i figured out the code in a little different way without a for loop.

Comment: Feel free to check it out at my website

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var images = [
        'http://placekitten.com/100/200',
        'http://placekitten.com/200/100',
    ];

    var img = document.getElementById( 'img' );

    setInterval(function () {
        img.src = img.src === images[0] ? images[1] : images[0];
    }, 1000 );

};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wkqpr/

---

If you have more than two images, you can do this:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var images = [
        'http://placekitten.com/100/200',
        'http://placekitten.com/200/100',
        'http://placekitten.com/200/150',
        'http://placekitten.com/150/300'
    ];

    images.current = 0;

    var img = document.getElementById( 'img' );

    setInterval(function () {
        img.src = images[ images.current++ ];
        if ( images.current === images.length ) images.current = 0;       
    }, 1000 );

};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wkqpr/1/

Comment: why did you use "===" in your last if statement?

Comment: @IlanBiala If the counter is equal to the array length, that means that I have to reset the counter.

Comment: @IlanBiala The `==` operator performs type coercion. The coercion rules are not intuitive and cannot be easily remembered. Therefore, it is recommended to not perform type coercion. You can do that by using the `===` operator, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop looks odd. Try that loop:

```
function changeImage(){
  if(!img.attributes["index"]){img.attributes["index"]=0;return;};
  img.attributes["index"]++;
  img.src=images[img.attributes["index"]];
}
window.onload=function(){
  window.img=document.getElementById("img");
  setInterval("changeImage()",5000)
}
```

Should work.
You'll notice that I store the image index in an attribute of the image, as opposed to
a global variable. I think the global is slightly faster, but storing it in the image
means you can easily expand this to multiple images if needed.
Also, the problem with your browser freezing was that the following code:

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
  //Some more stuff
  if(i==2){i-=2};
}
```

This loop is infinite, because whenever `i` reaches `2`, `i==2` becomes true, which means that iteration will reset `i` to `0` and start it all over again. The only way to prevent that would be a `break;` somewhere, which I don't see anywhere.
Tip: It is generally a bad idea to tamper with the index variable in for loops.

Comment: the reason i put that in there is so that the picture slideshow loops, because eventually i will have 25-30 pictures in there, and once it gets to 25/30, or in this case 2, I want it to loop back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeImage() 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {
        img.src = images[i];
     }
}


window.onload=function()
{
    setInterval(changeImage,5000);
}
```

Your last line in the for loop is completely useless and just complicate things,
Also, Your way of setting a window onload event is not standard!

EDIT: the `src` property is null because , obviously, your array size is only 2!!