# Javascript simple image slider

Tags: javascript, html, image, slider

I would like to have a simple picture slider. That slider should be in the header of the website and should switch between a small delay. I want it simple and named the pictures 1.jpg, 2.jpg and so on and they are in the folder "bilder".

I have tried a bit and here is my result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function picture_slider(){
        setInterval( switch_picture(), 3000 );
        return false;
    }

    function switch_picture() {
        for ( var i = 1; i < 7 ; i++ ) {     
            var pfad = "bilder/" + i + ".jpg";
            document.getElementById("bild").src = pfad; 

            i++;
        };
        return false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="picture_slider();">
    <img id="bild" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

I guess, that I did something wrong, because my browser is showing only one picture and is not switching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xebini/3/edit)***

On every loop you're iterating (`for` loop) over all your images, resulting in the latest one. Also use only `switch_picture` (instead of `switch_picture()`).

<sub>P.S: create an `0.jpg` image for this counter:</sub>

```
function picture_slider(){
    setInterval( switch_picture, 2000 ); // corrected removing "()"
}

var bild = document.getElementById("bild")
var i = 0; // Start from image 0.jpg

function switch_picture() { // don't iterate a loop in here!
  bild.src = "bilder/"+ (i++ % 7) +".jpg";
}
```

Comment: The browser is showing only picture "0" now. He is not going on to the next picture.

Comment: Sorry, for answering so late I went to the market. If I do this, I will get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of nulltest_2.html:16 switch_picture"

Comment: @c00L look I've posted you the exact code sample you need to use and also a workign demo to see how to use it. Should be easy to setup 7 lines of JS.

Answer (score 0):

I found something here: [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729915/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-src-of-null)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var i = 0;


var images = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]

function picture_slider(){
    setInterval( switch_picture, 2000 );
}

function switch_picture() {

    i++;

    if ( i >= images.length ) {

        i = 0;
    };

    var bild = document.getElementById("bild");
    bild.src = "bilder/" + images[i] + ".jpg"; 

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="picture_slider();">
<img id="bild" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// 1. images need to store in an Array
const images = [
  "img/pic-1.jpg",
  "img/pic-2.jpg",
  "img/pic-3.jpg",
  "img/pic-4.jpg",
  "img/pic-5.jpg",
  "img/pic-6.jpg",
  "img/pic-7.jpg"
];

// 7. getElementById by calling, store globally (do not call inside loop/setInterval performance will loose)
const imgElement= document.getElementById("slider-image");

// 2. set initial value for array index
let imgIndex = 0;

// 3. create setInterval()
const sliderInterval = setInterval(() => {
  // 6. check condition if length is finished then start again from 0
  if (imgIndex >= images.length) { // use >= because index start from 0 and length start from 1, if use just > then last element will be undefined
    imgIndex = 0;
  }
  // 5. testing
  // console.log(imgIndex);

  // 9. Dynamically change image src
  const imgUrl = images[imgIndex];
  imgElement.setAttribute('src', imgUrl);
  // 4. increase value by 1
  imgIndex++;
}, 1000);
```